# String Replace Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to play around my codes in ruby.

Here's what I got:

```
name = "Rol"
title = name
name = "Sam"
puts name
puts title

OUTPUT:
Sam
Rol

name = "Rol"
title = name
name.replace("Sam")
puts name
puts title

OUTPUT:
Sam
Sam
```

Basically I wondering why when I use reassignment equal sign it changes just the variable name and left the title with the old value. However upon using the replace method, it changes the value of both?

Any explanation in layman's term on this? Newbie in ruby here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple layman terms are:

- Assignments change variables.
- Mutation methods change objects.

Variables and objects are different things in Ruby. Each variable is a label that *points to* an object. Each method call is *sent* to an object. For convenience we often simplify discussion, because it is easy to say "The name is 'Sam'" when in detail we mean "The value stored in the String object pointed to by the name variable is 'Sam'"

***In your first example:***

The line `name = "Rol"` creates a new String object from the literal `"Rol"` and points the local variable `name` at it.

The line `title = name` points the local variable `title` to the same String object.

The line `name = "Sam"` creates a new String object from the literal `"Sam"` and points the local variable `name` at it. Now `name` and `title` point to different String objects.

At this point there are two independent String variables, with two different variables pointing at them, so any uses of them remain separate.

***In your second example:***

The line `name = "Rol"` creates a new String object from the literal `"Rol"` and points the local variable `name` at it.

The line `title = name` points the local variable `title` to the same String object.

The line `name.replace("Sam")` modifies the object. It doesn't matter which variable you used to access the object in the first place. `title.replace("Sam")` would have identical results, since it refers to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple.
When you call:

```
title = name
```

then both variables: title and name have reference to the same object, which is next modified by:

```
name.replace("Sam")
```

Answer (score 1):

`String#replace` replaces the content of the string referenced by `name`. However, it works at reference level as opposite to `=` that assigns a new String object to the left variable.

`name` is assigned to `title`, which means at that point in time both variables point to the same memory allocation. Since `replace` replaces the referenced string, the change is effectively propagated to both.

You get a better sense if you compare the `object_id` of the values. In the case of the assignment, the object ID changes because you effectively create and assign a new object:

```
name = "Rol"
title = name
name.object_id
# => 70336016119860
title.object_id
# => 70336016119860
name = "Sam"
name.object_id
# => 70336016085020
title.object_id
# => 70336016119860
```

For the case of `replace`, instead, the `object_id` doesn't change because you change the value directly without creating a new object.

```
name = "Rol"
title = name
name.object_id
# => 70336003479640
title.object_id
# => 70336003479640
name.replace("Sam")
name.object_id
# => 70336003479640
title.object_id
# => 70336003479640
```